# I have to refresh the page to see the change in REACTJS

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, api, react-hooks

I'm working on a simple project receving input and adding the input data to into database.

Here is my code:

```
 const [dataFromDB, setDataFromDB] = useState(null);

  const fetchDataFromDB = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(url);
      const data = await response.json();
      setDataFromDB(data);
      console.log(data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchDataFromDB();
  }, []);

  const addTextToDB = async (text) => {
    try {
      await fetch('http://localhost:3001/api/codes', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          text: text,
        }),
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const input = e.target.elements.name.value;
    addTextToDB(input);
    e.target.reset();
    fetchDataFromDB();
    setDataFromDB(dataFromDB);
    console.log(dataFromDB);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <label>
          Name:
          <input type="text" name="name" />
        </label>
        <input type="submit" value="ADD" />
      </form>
      <div>
        {dataFromDB &&
          dataFromDB.map((item) => <Item key={item._id} name={item.text} />)}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

First I fetch the data to show database to the user, then when a user input something by pressing the button the inputted value will be added to db. but to see the change I hvae to refresh the page or add two or more input after each other.

I have no idea where the problem is, after sumbitting the data I fetch the data again to receive the updated response from the database and then update the state of setDataFromDB to see the changes.

Answer (score 0):

In the `handleSubmit` function, you are calling the `fetchDataFromDB` function and then immediately setting the state of `setDataFromDB` to the current value of `dataFromDB`. This is unnecessary because you already update the state of `dataFromDB` inside the `fetchDataFromDB` function.

Moreover when you call `addTextToDB` and `fetchDataFromDB` in sequence like this, they will both start executing at the same time and run concurrently. Depending on the relative speeds of these functions and the server response times, it's possible that `fetchDataFromDB` may execute and update the state of `dataFromDB` before `addTextToDB` has completed adding the new data to the database. You should ensure that `addTextToDB` is fully completed and the database is updated before calling `fetchDataFromDB` to fetch the latest data from the server.

```
const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
  ...
  await addTextToDB(input);
  ...
  await fetchDataFromDB();
}
```

Comment: I call fethDataFromDB in handleSubmit after addTextToDB(input); since this function has already added the new entry to the database and fetching the data after that function brings the updated data.
I actually tried adding await keyword, but nothing has changed and I still need to refresh the page to see the change.

Comment: @it seems after adding await the rest of the code after addTextToDB never runs. I don't know why. I'm saying this because after pressing the button it should clear the input field. but it won't.